# default return value 1 in function with return type int?

Tags: c++, c

In this particular code, I am not able to see how it is outputting `1`. The control reaches the end of the function returning `int` type without encountering a `return` statement, so shouldn't there be a runtime error.
I tried passing some other values into the function, all print the same value `1` since `b` ends up to be an odd number before `0`.

I tried searching for default return value of an `int` returning function, but couldn't get a satisfactory answer. Some say, the default return value is 0, so why 1 is the output here?

```
int fun(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (b % 2 == 0) {
        return fun(a + a, b / 2);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", fun(6, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Falling off the end of a function is UB afaik. Your compiler should have emitted a warning.

Comment: Any reason you ignore compiler warnings? Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I bet you get a compiler warning

Comment: _"Some say, the default return value is 0"_ That's only true for the `main()` function.

Comment: No warning or error was thrown while compiling

Comment: @user0042: _"All we know is, it's called UB."_

Comment: @Lightness IIRC `return` is optional for `main()`.

Comment: Both C and C++ assumes that the programmers knows what they're doing, therefore there's no real run-time checking of *anything* in those languages. When a program crashes it's because the operating system detects a problem and kills the process. The compiler usually *warns* you about things that you maybe should not do, but it won't stop you. In other words, you get a very large gun, and it's up to you if you want to shoot yourself in the foot with it.

Comment: @hpotter97762: _"No warning or error was thrown while compiling"_ Then your warning level is set too low for some reason.

Comment: @user0042: I was completing your [accidental?] Top Gear quote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How do you set the warning level?

Comment: @Light Well, now I got it ;-P ... And no, there's nothing I'm doing _accidentally_ here.

Comment: @hpotter97762: Consult your particular compiler's documentation for all the information you could possibly want on how to use it.

Comment: "Some say" - who is that?

Comment: "No warning or error was thrown while compiling" - none need be. It's *your responsibility* to adhere to the rules of the language standard. It is *not* the compilers responsibility to tell you when you break the rules.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yup, I know that. But this was a question in a random c++ quiz. So, curious to know the answer.

Comment: Please please please please stop tagging things as both C and C++. They are two languages and can have wildly different answers.

Comment: And in this case they *do*. I didn't even consider this as a C++ question as the code very much looks like C, and it was tagged as C (too), and I came to answer this from the [tag:c] question listing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to not return a value from a function which is return type is not `void` (except `main` - `main` returns 0). Undefined behavior means anything can happen.

**Why do you get 1?** On x86, a function which returns `int`, returns the value of register `eax`. So, if you don't return a value in a function, the function will return whatever value of `eax` contain at exit.

Here's a possible explanation: at `b%2`, compiler puts `b` into `eax`, and `and`s it with 1. The result of `and` can be `0` or `1`, `eax` will contain one of these values. If the result is `1`, then `fun` exits without a return. So, at exit, `eax` contains `1`. And that is the value which is returned from the function.

Note: if you enable warnings, the compiler will warn you.

Note 2: some compilers put runtime error here, as you expected (for example, clang does it).

Note 3: some compilers emit compile errors for this (for example MSVC).

Comment: Although other answer has higher upvotes, I am accepting this one because it actually tells why answer is coming to be 1.

Comment: @hpotter97762: it gives an explanation that is plausible, but only examining the assembly code would confirm if the explanation is correct. It does not matter much anyway as any behavior is possible, including a computer crash or a blown fuse.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, falling off the end of a function that is supposed to return a value and not returning a value is undefined behavior.  You might get 0, you might get 1, or any other value that can be stored in the return type.

The only time this is not true is with `main`.  There is a clause in the standard that mandates the `main` will have a implicit `return 0;` if there is not one.

Comment: Not returning a value is *not* undefined behaviour. Using such a return value not returned is undefined though.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: _"`[C++14: 6.6.3/2]:` Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
behavior in a value-returning function."_

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It absolutely is.

Comment: Hmm, C++ yes, I saw this question tagged as C, it does not have undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The code does still have undefined behaviour in C though.

Answer (score 4):

> the default return value is 0

Only for `main`, which is special.

For your other functions that have a non-`void` return type, you *must* return a value. Period.

Failure to do so results in undefined behaviour, such as spontaneously inverting your underwear or cutting off your mum's hair. Or getting `1`.

So:

```
int fun(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
       return 0;

    if (b % 2 != 0)
       return 1;

    return fun(a + a, b / 2);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", fun(6,3));
}
```

Comment: I know this is undefined behaviour. Still, this question was there in a random c++ quiz. Hence, the question....

Comment: @hpotter97762: _"I know this is undefined behaviour"_ Ehm then why the question? That's the answer. Anything can happen. And, since you already knew that, you're just wasting all our time...

Comment: PS the quiz is broken unless this is a valid answer to it

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the behavior is undefined: falling off the end of an `int` returning function without a `return` statement has undefined behavior. It could return `1`, or `2` or anything else... as a matter of fact, depending on how it is compiled, it does!

Here is the assembly output for `gcc 7.1 -O2` 64-bit as produced by [Godbolt's fantastic compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/HpbzcY):

```
fun(int, int):
        test    esi, esi
        je      .L5
        test    sil, 1
        je      .L8
        rep ret
.L8:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     eax, esi
        shr     eax, 31
        add     esi, eax
        sar     esi
        add     edi, edi
        call    fun(int, int)
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L5:
        mov     eax, esi
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     esi, 3
        mov     edi, 6
        call    fun(int, int)
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

The return value for function `fun` is stored into register `eax`. Careful analysis shows that when invoked as `fun(6, 3)`, `fun` actually does not modify `eax`. This register is not modified by `main()` prior to calling `fun(6, 3)`, so it must come from the C startup code. I suspect `eax` contains the value of the `argc` argument to `main()`, 1 plus the number of arguments passed on the command line.  You can try invoking your program with an argument and see if it outputs `2`, etc.

Of course, this is only a guess as

- your compiler might generate code which outputs `1` for a different reason.
- the C startup code might set `eax` to `1` for another cause.

Try different compilers and optimization settings on the godbolt online compiler and see what it generates. For example `clang -O2` compiles `fun()` to always return `0`.

Comment: Did this by passing 6 and 3 as the command line aguments, still answer 1, I used gnu g++ 5.4.0. But thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @hpotter97762: try `gcc` instead of `g++` and pass `-O1`.  With `-O0`, the explanation given by *geza* is the correct one as you can verify in the assembly output.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard allows a function that is declared and defined to return a value, to end without a `return` statement. Calling such a function has well-defined behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void) {
    printf("Hello world");
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
}
```

However, in C **using** the return value from a function that didn't return a value via a `return` statement has undefined behaviour. This is explicitly mentioned in [C11 6.9.1p12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12)

> 12 If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Thus in your example,

```
fun(6, 3);
```

is fine, as is the whole function definition, but using the return value as in

```
printf("%d", fun(6, 3));
```

will summon the [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

---

C++ is a different beast though, there omitting the return statement itself has undefined behaviour - but GCC seems to ignore it in this case - perhaps to allow the (questionable) compilation of C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Well, in C, yes. Not in C++ though. OP mistagged but has indicated that the question came from a C++ quiz.